# How to access return value from SQLite executesql in Angular

Tags: angular, sqlite, ionic-framework

This is my query to return true if any records are in the table and return false if there is no records.

```
this.offlineDBService.db
          .executeSql(
            `SELECT EXISTS (SELECT Id FROM Session WHERE Id = ${Id})`,
            []
          )
          .then((val) => {
            console.log("returned response: ", val.rows.item(0));
          })
```

this console log logs return as following object. 1 means true.

```
{EXISTS (SELECT SessionId FROM SessionHeader WHERE SessionId = 2430193654737): 1}
```

But how can i access that value "1"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your SQL query to:

`SELECT EXISTS (SELECT Id FROM Session WHERE Id = ${Id}) as 'exists'`

and get the value by doing:

`val.rows.item(0)['exists']`